# How can $^E be compared with a number?

Tags: perl, error-handling

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220688/180275 the answer suggests that (after an `open`) `$^E` can be compared with *0x20* to determine if a file is being used by another process:

```
open ($fh, "<", "the-file");
if ($^E == 0x20) {
  ...
}
```

I have tried that and it works. *However*, if I print the value of `$^E` I get a string (`The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`).

How then is the comparison to a number still possible?

This is on Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>perl -E"open my $fh, '<', 'nonexistent'; say 0+$^E; say ''.$^E;"
2
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Like `$!`, `$^E` is a dualvar, a scalar that contains two values. One's a string, and one's a number.

```
>perl -E"say $^E = 0x20;"
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```